# Prove or disprove: If L : V → U and M : U → V are linear mappings such that (M ◦ L)(x) = x for all x ∈ V, then M is onto.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that a map is onto if for every vector in its range, there exists a vector in the domain that maps to it.

By the definition of the composition we're given, isn't it obvious that $M$ is onto? the vector that maps to $v$ for all $v \in V$ would just be $L(v) \rightarrow u$, for all $u \in U$.

Not sure how to prove something so obvious (unless I'm wrong, and it's not completely obvious).

Comment: I think you're absolutely right, it's obvious and there is nothing to prove. Given any $x$ in $V$, $Lx$ maps to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's obvious. But your explanation is a bit incorrect. For any $x\in V$, there is $x\in V$ such that $M(L(x))=x$. Which means that $L(x)\in U$ is the required preimage of x (under M) in U.
You wrote "for all $u \in U$" which is incorrect as $L$ might not be onto.

Comment: "such that $M(L(x))$"?

Comment: @Ludolila I'd made a mistake. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* that simple, although you're garbling the explanation a bit.

> *the vector that maps to v for all v ∈ V would just be L(v) => u, for all u ∈ U.*

For each vector $v$, you need something to map to $v$ via $M$. "the vector that maps to $v$ for all $v\in V$" means something different. Bringing in $u$ is just one too many quantifiers and variables: it's not necessary.

It's true that $(M\circ L)(v)=v$ implies that for each $v\in V$, $M$ maps $L(v)\mapsto v$ establishing that $M$ is onto $V$.